# How can I create a section or category in Craft 3 that shares its entries (i.e. not multi-site)?

Tags: craft3, multi-site

Is it currently possible to create a section or category that shares the same entries across multiple sites? I can currently create a section, and once I save an entry, it is propagated to all sites.  However, those entries are then unique to each site.  I'm looking for a way to share a section's entries across multiple sites so that if an entry is modified, those changes are shared and reflected across all sites.